# Why is 1 the value of the variable var after entering the if-statement?

Tags: c, comparison, logical-operators

Here you can see the listing and I know that it is an assignment in the if-statement and not a comparison. So please no advises that you know it better. I just want to know why the value of **var is 1** after the asssignment in the if-statement.

```
int var = 0;
if(var = -5 || 5)
{
    // Value of var is 1, but why? Shouldn´t it be -5 or 5?
    printf("%d", var);
}
```

Comment: If you add braces it makes more sense: `var = (-5 || 5)`

Comment: Did you mean `==`? And did you also mean `if(var == -5 || var == 5)` ? There must be a higher purpose in the code than to evaluate `-5 || 5`, both operands are `true.`

Comment: "Shouldn´t it be -5 or 5" suggests that they do want assignment.

Comment: @Carcigenicate did you mean *not*? It's a frequent new coders' mistake to try to make multiple `or` conditions like this.

Comment: No. They wouldn't expect `var` to be something other than `0` unless they intended assignment. I don't know what their intent is otherwise, but an equality check doesn't seem likely. I'm aware of the common mistake, but that doesn't seem to be the case here based on their comment.

Comment: This looks like something like "I wish I could write this way and get such and such results. But it looks like I can't. Why?" question. Instead, please learn the C syntax and what it does, and then use it to achieve the results you need. C is not a language you can learn by experimentation.

Comment: This listing is not from me, it is an example from an exam.

Comment: [My answer](https://pastebin.com/Dj3tJHFd)

Answer (score 0):

In C `(x||y)` is a boolean expression -- an expression who's result is always true (1) of false (0).
The same is true for `&&` (and) and `!` (not).

And, `if (x = y)` is the same as `if (y)` with the side effect of assigning y to x. That is:

To evaluate:

```
if (var = -5 || 5)  ...
```

Is it

```
if ((var = -5) || 5)   ...
```

or?

```
if (var = (-5 || 5))   ...
```

It is the second, because || has higher precedence: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Because:

```
(-5 || 5) ---> 1
```

...
we now have...

```
if (var = 1)  ...
```

1 is assigned to var  (`=` is assignment, `==` is value equality)
Because in C, the statement `a=b` is also an expression who's new value is the new value if a, we now have:

```
if (var) ...
```

... because tests true because `var` is `1`, and non-zero integers are true in C.